# Can't get jqueryUI datepicker to store date object instead of string

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parsing, date, datepicker

I can't get the jqueryUI datepicker to store a date object as it's value opposed to a string.  Everything else with the datepicker works fine for me, but the form I am submitting the value to requires a date object and not a string value.  The trick is after everytime the user selects a new date, the value being stored in the datepicker should be a date object.  I've tried the following:

```
  $('#DP2').datepicker({           
             onSelect: function() {
                $("#DP2").val($("#DP2").datepicker("getDate"));
             }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#DP2').datepicker({           
         onSelect: function() {
            var d = new Date();
            console.log($("#DP2").datepicker('getDate'));
            d = $("#DP2").datepicker('getDate');
         }
  });
```

This will return date object

```
 $("#DP2").datepicker('getDate');
```

You had this:

```
 $("#DP2").val($("#DP2").datepicker("getDate"));
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. 

  <cause type="java.lang.Throwable" description="cause" />
      <localizedMessage type="java.lang.String" description="String">Type mismatch. Expected "Date" type, but found: "java.lang.String". Value: "05-02-2012"</localizedMessage>

Comment: @JeffSilva - I edited answer , the result needs to be put used like that

Comment: I still don't see it with that code... Maybe I don't undestand the question, but with yours, I get the date as a string ¿?

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried with `$("#DP2").datepicker()` instead of `$("#DP2").datepicker("getDate")`

Like:

```
 $('#DP2').datepicker({           
             onSelect: function() {
                $("#DP2").val($("#DP2").datepicker());
             }
  }); ​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Egs6S/

---

**EDIT:**

### New example with the object as result. http://jsfiddle.net/Egs6S/1/

```
 $('#DP2').datepicker({           
             onSelect: function(event, ui) {
                console.log(ui); // This is the Object
             }
 });
```

Good luck, I hope it's helps!

Comment: that's going to return the string Date , not date object

Comment: strange... that's exactly what I get with your code XD , Look in my example the _#result_a_ div

Comment: it is going to look the same - but he wanted a javascript date object - they are going to look identical as a string but trying to add 10 days to yours

Comment: You're right... that's not the object. I Will edit the answer with a new solution.